# running a function in python for 'x' no. of seconds only

Tags: python

I want to run a python script (or a function defined within it) for some time interval say, 67 seconds. I tried the following but the program won't stop running.

```
strt = time.time() + 67
print(strt)

with open('csv_data.csv', 'w') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1)

    if z1serial.is_open:
        while True:
            while (time.time() < strt):
                clock.tick(60)
                size = z1serial.inWaiting()
                if size:
                    data = (z1serial.read(size))
                    writer.writerow(data)
                    writer.writerow('',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a nested loop here and the outer loop is an infinite loop. The inner loop will stop after a specific time period, but the outer will not. Remove the outer loop

```
with open('csv_data.csv', 'w') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1)

    if z1serial.is_open:
        while (time.time() < strt):
             clock.tick(60)
             size = z1serial.inWaiting()
             if size:
                 data = (z1serial.read(size))
                 writer.writerow(data)
                 writer.writerow('',)
```

Comment: thanks @e4c5 but i need that outer loop for continuous fetching of data from a serial port

Comment: Well you want the program to exit after 67 second, how do you expect to do that when you have an infinite loop?

Comment: sorry my bad, I was a bit confused. Thank You. It ran finally.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project.

Comment: Really appreciate it. Thanks again.